# How can i read from a specific process it's memory for a specific value change the value and write it back to the process memory?

Tags: c#, winforms, memory

I'm using: ProcessMemoryReaderLib.dll referenced it to my project.
This is the form1 code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using ProcessMemoryReaderLib;
using System.IO;

namespace ProcessMemory
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        ProcessMemoryReader pReader;
        int store;
        IntPtr score_addr;
        byte[] write;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            for (int i = 0 ; i < 2; i++)
            {
            store = 0;
            pReader = new ProcessMemoryReader(); //create a new writer - reader
            Process[] hProcessSnap; //create an array containing all running processes
            Process hProcess = null;
            hProcessSnap = Process.GetProcesses(); //Load all processes in the array

            // The address
            score_addr = (IntPtr)00000005;//(IntPtr)0x1007800;
            write = new byte[4];
            write = BitConverter.GetBytes(0);

            for (int n = 0; n < hProcessSnap.Length; n++)
            {
                // ProcessName is not Unique, there could be many matching processes
                //   and this loop will only return the last one.
                if (hProcessSnap[n].ProcessName == "FlashPlayerPlugin_11_8_800_168")
                    hProcess = hProcessSnap[n];

            }

            pReader.ReadProcess = hProcess;
            pReader.OpenProcess();

                }


        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pReader.WriteProcessMemory(score_addr, write, out store);
        }
    }
}
```

I added my own for loop.
The idea in general is to find in a specific process in it's memory a specific value.
For example: score_addr = (IntPtr)00000005;
00000005 = 5 in Hex

Now i found many places in the memory in the specific process memory with this value.
Now i'm going to the process change something inside doing some changes the process is a program so i change the value i wanted if it was 5 now it's 4

So now i will search in the process memory for the value 4. So it was 5 now it's 4 the results should be much narrow for example only 3-4 places in the memory of the process will be with 4.

Now i want to take this 3-4 addresses change theire values each one to 8.
So now if i will look in my program(process) i will see that teh value had changed to 8.

1. Scan the memory of the process name.
2. Locate all places/addresses in the proces memory with the specific value for example 5.
3. Go to the process/program change there something so now the value 5 is 4.
4. Scan again from the last place in memory for the value 4 locate all places/addresses of the value 4.
5. Change in all the results of the value 4 change the value of each memory address to value for example 8.
6. Write back to the exact place this results of the value 4 with it's now values changed to 8.

So if i will look now at my process it will be now show the value 8.

How can i do it ?

Answer (score 0):

I once was also doing a similar stuff and trying to figure out how to do `2. Search for a value`. I haven't made it yet, so note that the answer is incomplete.

I access the memory(given specific addresses) with the methods below.

```
public int GetInteger(int memoryAddress, uint bytes) {
    int bytesRead;
    byte[] memoryValue;
    if(bytes == 1) {
        #region single byte
        byte[] temp = pReader.ReadProcessMemory((IntPtr)memoryAddress, bytes, out bytesRead);
        memoryValue = new byte[4];
        memoryValue[0] = temp[0];
        memoryValue[1] = memoryValue[2] = memoryValue[3] = 0;
        // little endian
        #endregion
    } else if(bytes == 2) {
        #region two bytes
        byte[] temp = pReader.ReadProcessMemory((IntPtr)memoryAddress, bytes, out bytesRead);
        memoryValue = new byte[4];
        memoryValue[0] = temp[0];
        memoryValue[1] = temp[1];
        memoryValue[2] = memoryValue[3] = 0;
        #endregion
    } else if(bytes == 3) {
        #region three bytes
        byte[] temp = pReader.ReadProcessMemory((IntPtr)memoryAddress, bytes, out bytesRead);
        memoryValue = new byte[4];
        memoryValue[0] = temp[0];
        memoryValue[1] = temp[1];
        memoryValue[2] = temp[2];
        memoryValue[3] = 0;
        #endregion
    } else if(bytes == 4) {
        memoryValue = pReader.ReadProcessMemory((IntPtr)memoryAddress, bytes, out bytesRead);
    } else {
        // do more if you have to deal with values like eight-byte values.
    }
    int result = BitConverter.ToInt32(memoryValue, 0);
    if(result < 0) {
        throw new OverflowException(result + "(possible overflow)");
    }
    return result;
}

public string GetString(int memoryAddress, uint bytes) {
    int bytesRead;
    byte[] memoryValue = pReader.ReadProcessMemory((IntPtr)memoryAddress, bytes, out bytesRead);
    Encoding encoding = Encoding.Default;
    string result = encoding.GetString(memoryValue, 0, (int)bytes);
    result = result.TrimEnd('\0');
    return result;
}

public void SetInteger(int memoryAddress, int value, uint bytes) {
    byte[] temp = new byte[bytes];
    for(int i = 0; i < bytes; i++) {
        temp[i] = 0;
    }
    byte[] byteValue = BitConverter.GetBytes(value);
    pReader.WriteProcessMemory((IntPtr)memoryAddress, byteValue, bytes);
}

public void SetString(int memoryAddress, string value, uint bytes) {
    byte[] byteValue = new byte[bytes];
    for(int i = 0; i < bytes; i++) {
        byteValue[i] = 0;
    }
    Encoding encoding = Encoding.Default;
    byteValue = encoding.GetBytes(value);
    pReader.WriteProcessMemory((IntPtr)memoryAddress, byteValue, bytes);
}
```

If you know all the addresses you want to access, this should be enough.

I tried to search for a value with something like this

```
// NEVER DO THAT.
List<int> candidates = new List<int>();
for(int i = 0; i < Int32.MaxValue; i++) {
    //if you don't know the byte size of the searchee, it gets even worse. :s
    //for(int bytes = 1; j < 4; j++)
    if(GetInteger(i, bytes) == THE_VALUE_TO_SEARCH_FOR) {
        candidates.Add(i);
    }
}
```

and then my PC exploded. (no =D)

Find out something else and please share if any.